# How can I sort a dictionary keys by how many times a specific character appears in the key?

Tags: python, dictionary

For example, I have the dict：

```
{"aaaa": 158,"aaaaaaaaaapppppp": 170,"ooooo":14}
```

I want it to be sorted based on how many times the character "a" appears in the dict. I have tried

```
newDict = dict(sorted(oldDict.items(),key=lambda item: item.count("x"))）
```

but it simply leaves the keys unsorted.

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered data structures. It can't sort. If you want to sort, use ordered data structure

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt is basically correct, but the item is a tuple of key and value pairs, so you just need the first element in that pair (`item[0]`).

> Changed in version 3.7: Dictionary order is guaranteed to be insertion order. This behavior was an implementation detail of CPython from 3.6.

[Source docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html)

Assuming all of your keys are strings, you can use the `count` method on them to sort the new dictionary in ascending order based on the number of occurrences of the `key_sort_letter` as follows:

```
d = {"aaaa": 158, "aaaaaaaaaapppppp": 170, "ooooo":14} 
keys_sort_letter = 'a'
>>> dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda item: item[0].count(keys_sort_letter)))
{'ooooo': 14, 'aaaa': 158, 'aaaaaaaaaapppppp': 170}
```

The first key 'ooooo' has zero occurrences of the letter "a", the second key has four occurrences and the last key has ten.

To ensure the keys are strings, you could cast them as such:

```
lambda item: str(item[0]).count(keys_sort_letter))
```

Answer (score 0):

A dict is *unsorted* by definition. In your newDict assignment, by calling `dict()` on the result, you are re-creating a dictionary from the sorted result, which effectively unsorts it.

If you want the results sorted, you must store them in some other data structure. The result of sorted() is a list of tuples where each tuple has 2 elements: key, value. This is usually well-suited to iteration.

Comment: I am doing the same thing for another dict, but sorting by which is alphabetically larger and the newDict stays sorted, so I don't think that can be the case.

Comment: Dictionaries are _guaranteed_ to be sorted as of python 3.7 (and implemented in cython 3.6). "Changed in version 3.7: Dictionary order is guaranteed to be insertion order. This behavior was an implementation detail of CPython from 3.6." https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html